# Php Recording a Live streaming to a file

Tags: php, streaming, live, fwrite

Hi i have a live streaming code and i stream my web cam on the local host.

Here is my stream file code

```
<?php

function flush_buffers(){
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_start();
}


header('Content-Type: video/mpeg');
$stream = fopen( 'http://localhost:8080/stream.mp2v', "rb" );
#$save = fopen("save.mp4", "w");
while ( ! feof( $stream ) )
{

    $response = fread( $stream, 8192 ); 
    echo $response;
    #fwrite($save,$stream);
    flush_buffers();
}

fclose( $stream );
fclose($save);
exit();
```

What I need to do is record this live streaming simultaneously to a file here i stated save.mp4 in my code.I tried to do that with fwrite but when i run the program with this code i could see my webcam running but it could not record anything to save.mp4.I dont think fwrite is a suitable function for my purpose.I need help in this point.What should i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should have written `fwrite($save,$response);` instead `of fwrite($save,$stream);`. It worked in this way.