# How can I make my server allow my PHP script process to run for 75 minutes instead of disconnecting after only 45 minutes?

Tags: php, cron, ini, cron-task

I am trying to save an mp4 file from audio live stream by PHP script initiated by cron job.

It's expected to work for 75 minutes, but the problem is it runs for only 45 minutes. I found that the server may disconnect the process and not allow the script to run for such a long time.

I checked my PHP ini settings from CPanel and I found this:

```
allow_url_fopen 
 Enabled
display_errors      
 Disabled
enable_dl       
 Disabled
file_uploads    
 Enabled
max_execution_time      
30
max_input_time      
60
max_input_vars  
1000
memory_limit        
256M
post_max_size       
512M
session.gc_maxlifetime      
1440
session.save_path   
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74
upload_max_filesize 
512M
zlib.output_compression     
 Disabled
```

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php

function flush_buffers(){
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_start();
}

$path = __DIR__ . '/save.mp4';

$stream = fopen( 'request url', "rb" );
$save = fopen($path, "w");
$startTime = time();
$finishTime = $startTime + (60*75);
while ( $finishTime >= time() ){

    $response = fread( $stream, 8192 ); 
    fwrite($save,$response);
    flush_buffers();
}

fclose( $stream );
fclose($save);
exit();

?>
```

Comment: What is with the flush_buffers command?  Is this a command line php script?  You have no output in the script, and those functions are for granular control of web server output.

Comment: Sorry I dont know usage of it .. i took the code from this answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459509/php-recording-a-live-streaming-to-a-file

Comment: You don't understand my point.  You don't need that function, and you should not be using it, especially when you don't understand what it does.

Comment: Ok I will remove this func .. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of shared server hosting limitations. The shared server does not allow any script to run for more than 45 minutes (VPS & dedicated run normally).

I get around this issue by run 2 separate cron jobs (40 minutes between every job) instead of one big one.

- The 1st job creates a file and saves data to it.
- The 2nd job appends data onto the same file for the rest of stream duration.

Every script works for 40 minutes only in order to avoid the server killing the script.

Here is my final code:

```php
<?php

// Ignore user aborts and allow the script to run forever
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$path = __DIR__ . '/save.mp3';

$stream = fopen( 'my url', "rb" );
$save = fopen($path, "a");
$startTime = time();
$finishTime = $startTime + (60*40);
while ( $finishTime >= time() ){

    $response = fread( $stream, 8192 ); 
    fwrite($save,$response);
}

fclose( $stream );
fclose($save);
exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try `ignore_user_abort()` function with `set_time_limit()` function. The `ignore_user_abort(true)` function with the argument `true` lets the script run even if the client is disconnected. And set zero as the argument to the `set_time_limit(0)` function to run the script forever.

So add the following code snippet to the top of your script. This could help you.

```
<?php

// Ignore user aborts and allow the script to run forever
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you .. this solution is logic but I tried it now disconnected after 45 minutes .. please note I am on shared plan cpanel not dedicated server if this affect any thing

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that too. Shared hosting normally has some limitations. Definitely that is the reason. Sometimes contacting the hosting provider to make the script execution time more works. So you may try that.

Comment: Yes you are right .. I contacted them now and told me this is limitation issue .. they dont accept script running for more than 45 min .. I mailed them now asking to increase limit if available .. but if they refused what is the best approach in your opinion .. make 2 cron jobs and append data in one file or can execute new php script from original script when time reach 45 min  (if applicable i dont know) ?

Comment: I don't see any good approach if you stick to the shared hosting plan. What best approach to me is you go for a VPS.